# Java: Update an existing entry in products map: update the count of the purchases of this product

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I need to insert or update an entry for a txt file using the ProductId HashMap. I am not familiar with HashMap. I have to use HashMap even though TreeSet could work too. I know I would have to use an iterator but I don't know how. The file reads in the console so there is no problems with that.

Problem:
I need to reference to a certain productID key (which is 1005) to update the ItemPrice to $90.

```
public class StoreSales {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        readFile("Sales.txt", customer);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(customer);

}

public static void readFile(String file, List<Customer> cust) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Map<Integer, Customer> CustomerID = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Customer> ProductID = new HashMap<>();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            cust.add(new Customer(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1], arr[2], Integer.parseInt(arr[3]), arr[4], Double.parseDouble(arr[5]), Integer.parseInt(arr[6])));

            if (CustomerID.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]))) {
                CustomerID.get(arr[0]).getItemsPurchased();

            }
            if (ProductID.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]))) {
                ProductID.get(arr[3]).getSingleItemPrice();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement.  At least point out which lines of code have the problem.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The easiest way to is re-write the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarification

`I need to insert or update an entry for a txt file using the ProductId HashMap.`

If you wish to do the above then you need to use BufferedWriter to write into a file the concept of using HashMap is quite easy actual 
HashMap --> Understand the concept first, think of it as a Bank/Locker to get the valuable item/items you need the key, hashMap works exactly like that

Now if you require only values
`for(String str:map.values())`
in your case 
`for(Customer cust:ProductID.values())` // getting all values of customer present in Map

based on the code you have written, I'm assuming this as you haven't provided the entire code, but you haven't assigned any values to your Map so you will not get any data, you might even be getting a exception

You need to iterate  only if you require both key and value pair values

`for (Map.Entry<Integer, Customer> entry : ProductID.entrySet()) 
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Customer = " + entry.getValue());`

Hope this was helpful,
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

`Problem: I need to reference to a certain productID key (which is 1005) to update the ItemPrice to $90`

`if (ProductID.containsKey(1005)) {
                ProductID.get(1005).setSingleItemPrice(90);
            }`

please be more specific as to what you want next time :)